# include_once(/payment.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

i am using laravel to develop an payments application for that i am using [this package](https://github.com/easebuzz/paywitheasebuzz-php-lib)as they mentioned i clone the repository and move **easebuz-lib** directory inside the project folder,i have created on controller called **payController** and in this one i included as they mentioned(    `include_once('easebuzz-lib/easebuzz_payment_gateway.php');`) i changed according to the project folder it's  working fine but it's failing inside the other easebuzz_payment_gateway.php i could not able to figure out why it's failing can you please help me to fix this issue..?

`payController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Easebuzz;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;

include_once('../easebuzz-lib/easebuzz_payment_gateway.php');



class PayController extends Controller
{
    public function pay(Request $request){
        $key = config('constants.easebuzz')['merchant_key'];
        $salt = config('constants.easebuzz')['salt'];
        $env = config('constants.easebuzz')['env'];
        $easebuzzObj = new Easebuzz($key,$salt,$env);
        $postData =  [
                        "txnid" => 'TEST'.rand(0,100),
                        "amount" => '10.00',
                        "firstname" => 'sai',
                        "email" =>'sai',
                        "phone" => 'sai',
                        "productinfo" => 'This is for dummy test',
                        "surl" => "http://127.0.0.1:8000/response.php",
                        "furl" => "http://127.0.0.1:8000/response.php",
                    ];

        $easebuzzObj->initiatePaymentAPI($postData);
        var_dump($easebuzzObj);
    }
}
```

`easebuzz_payment_gateway.php`

```
 public function initiatePaymentAPI($params, $redirect=True){
            //initially it was include_once('payment.php') i changed to following way
           include_once('/payment.php');

            // generate transaction ID and push into $params array
            // $txnid = substr(hash('sha256', mt_rand() . microtime()), 0, 20);
            // $params['txnid'] = $txnid;
            return initiate_payment($params, $redirect, $this->MERCHANT_KEY, $this->SALT, $this->ENV);
        }
```

[image]

`composer.json`

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.75",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.11",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.10",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        },
        "classmap": ["easebuzz-lib/"]

    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to not use `include_once` here, instead add path to this library to classmap in `composer.json`:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": ["path/to/easebuzz-lib/"]
    }
}
```

then run:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Also you should not edit files in library, especially restore this thing:

```php
include_once('/payment.php');
```

to original:

```php
include_once('payment.php');
```

Comment: after this still it's failing inthe same line include

Comment: Are you correctly added path to library in `composer.json`? Post full content of it

Comment: "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        },
        "classmap": ["easebuzz-lib/"]

    },

Comment: is the `easebuzz-lib` folder really next to the file `composer.json`, and not inside `app`? I just tried to add this library in same way that I posted, and it works fine

Comment: it's equvivalent to the app directory

Comment: i have added picture in the question please check it

Comment: Cannot redeclare response() (previously declared in /home/deploy/payment/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php:716) {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\ErrorHandler\\Error\\FatalError(code: 0): Cannot redeclare response() (previously declared in /home/deploy/payment/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php:716) at /home/deploy/payment/easebuzz-lib/payment.php:739)

Comment: In logs i am getting this type of error

Answer (score -1):

Go to payment.php and add line for check whether function exists

```
if(!function_exists('response')) {
```